# Attaching a Database .MDF without Visual Studio copying it to another folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to attach a database from a folder on my laptop.

Problem is when I attach it in Visual Studio 2010, using Solution Explorer, it makes a copy of the database under where the project is.

I want the database to not be copied under that folder, but left in its original place.

Any advice?

I'm using C# Window Form Dev Project

Comment: The smart thing to do here is to make it work *exactly* like it does on your user's machine.  Where you won't put the mdf in the EXE directory either, you can't write to it.  So put it in AppData and setup your connection string to point to it.  And of course it won't be copied anymore either.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to attach the .mdf file using solution explorer, in VS 2010

1. Go to Tools
2. Select - Connect to Database
3. In add connection window click on Change button under Data Source
4. Select MS SQL Server DB File in the list, click OK
5. Browse for the file and type your id and password if required, click OK
6. Your database will come under Server Explorer
7. Now right click on the database and click properties
8. In properties window get the connection string and use it in your application

Its good to put the db file in application under App_Data folder when you are going to distribute your application because it does not need the connection string to be changed.